# erlang: Count items in list of tuples

Tags: erlang

I have the following list of items
`[{id, user1, category1}, {id, user2, category1}, {id, user1, category2}....],`
where id is unique, and user/category can be repeated. I am trying to figure out how to get stats from the list, e.g.

`[{user1, category1, 20}, {user1, category2, 30}..]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using the lists:foldl/3 function.

```
F = fun({_,User,Cat},Accumulator) -> 
        N = maps:get({User,Cat},Accumulator,0),
        maps:put({User,Cat},N+1,Accumulator) end.
CountMap = lists:foldl(F,#{},InputListe),
```

this returns a map of the form `#{{user1, category1} => 20, {user1, category2} => 30 ...}`

if you really need a list then you have to transform the map:

```
CountList = maps:fold(fun({User,Cat}, Count, Acc) -> [{User,Cat,Count}|Acc] end,[],CountMap).
```

*I have used an intermediary Map because if the input list is big, then it gives fast accesses and fast update compare to a solution where you work directly in the output list. It costs a lot to retrieve information in a list (in average parse half of the list), and it costs also a lot to modify it (in average copy half of the list*

for an input list of 200 000 elements, it took 94msec to generate the map and convert it into a list on my laptop, and 219ms for 500000 elements.

Answer (score 3):

Although [Pascal's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1635979/pascal) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39577483/49197) is a good universal solution, for small datasets (like up to 15 000) you can use this version using `lists:sort/1` which is significantly faster for them.

```
main(L) ->
    count(lists:sort(transform(L))).

count([]) -> [];
count([H|T]) ->
    count(H, T, 1, []).

count(H, [H|T], N, Acc) -> count(H, T, N+1, Acc);
count({U, C}, [H|T], N, Acc) -> count(H, T, 1, [{U, C, N}|Acc]);
count({U, C}, [], N, Acc) -> [{U, C, N}|Acc].

transform(L) ->
    transform(L, []).

transform([], Acc) -> Acc;
transform([{_, User, Category}|T], Acc) ->
    transform(T, [{User, Category}|Acc]).
```

**Edit**:

The key point to determine which algorithm will be faster is a proportion of unique keys. If there is big dataset but with a small amount of unique `{User, Category}` the solution using maps will be faster. If it is the other way around, `lists:sort/1` will be faster. In other words, the size of list vs. map matter.